# Containerized Grafana unable to connect Containerized Prometheus

Tags: docker, prometheus, grafana

I am getting the following error when trying to connect Prometheus to Grafana.

*Post "http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9090: connect: connection refused - There was an error returned querying the Prometheus API.*

I don't get the same error when I try doing this locally.

I am not sure what is going on, because this works at a local level.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that inside a container 'localhost' is only what is inside that specific container (only grafana is running in the grafana container).

In this case you will need to use the name of the prometheus container instead of localhost i.e "http://prometheus:9090" and ensure that both containers are on the same docker network.

Docker can resolve resolve the container name as a hostname, within the docker network.

Comment: Thanks Vaugh! That makes a lot of sense. I got it to work.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept my answer if it solved your problem :) If you work with Docker often it might be worth looking into the networking docs. The main one to learn would be bridged networking.